# Expression to calculate % in a report

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportbuilder, power-bi-report-server, reportserver

I am building a report(report server project) using the Data Tools. I have a column *Quantity* it has a *Total*.
I need another column that calculate the share(%) of each line in the *Quantity* comparing to the *Total*.

The expression would be: Line_1_Share =  Quantity_of_line_1/Total.

I tried =[Sum(Total/Quantity)] but it does not even accept as a valid expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you right-click the textboxes that contain your working 'Quantity' and 'Total' values and look at the expressions you will see the correct format.

For exmaple your 'Quantity' expression might be something like

```
=Fields!Quantity.Value
```

or if it is in a grouped row it might be

```
=SUM(Fields!Quantity.Value)
```

your 'Total' expression might also be

```
=SUM(Fields!Quantity.Value)
```

When you use `SUM()` (or any similar aggregate) then the scope of the expression decides what is included in the sum. The scope can be a single row, a row group or an entire dataset. If you do not specify a scope then the position of the textbox determines the scope.

So, if you have a simple table with no grouping other than the total line and your dataset name is `dataset1` then your expression would need to be

```
=Fields!Quantity.Value / SUM(Fields!Quantity.Value, "dataset1")
```

The above reads .... "For the current row, take the Quantity and divide is but the sum of all Quantities that are within the entire dataset called dataset1"

If this does not help, post your current report design including and row and/or column groups.